# What is an alternative expression to "this"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

What is an alternative expression to "this"? As in:

> Medicine is very important. **This**
>   can be ascertained from the fact
>   that...

I'm looking for a "synonym".

Comment: In this case, you can probably just use "Medicine is very important, as can be ascertained from the fact that..." However, depending on how long the part after the ... is, it may be unwieldy.

Comment: If it appeals to you, skip the synonym and let the context work for you.  "Medicine is very important.  Consider the fact that..."

Comment: **The importance of medicine can be ascertained by the fact that...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There do exist alternatives:

> Medicine is very important. *Such* can be ascertained from the fact that...
>
> Medicine is very important. *As much* can be ascertained from the fact that...
>
> Medicine is very important. *That* be ascertained from the fact that...
>
> Medicine is very important. *So obvious a conclusion* can be ascertained from the fact that...

And so on. Be creative, don't let yourself be boxed in by a single word.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a single word, that's why I asked for an alternative expression. I like such. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think any of these alternatives is any clearer than a simple "this", and #4 is pretentiously verbose.

Comment: @David Rivers: I agree. The point, as I see it, is what does one do when one gets tired of using the demonstrative pronoun? And I might point out that by labeling these possible constructions *alternative* I was not implying that they were *better*.

Comment: One thing about purely “function” words is that they usually don’t have synonyms the way noun and verbs, or adjectives and adverbs, do. Look back at the previous sentence and notice which words are irreplaceable.

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear, I don't think there exists any word close enough to be considered a synonym. The closest words would be "that" and "it", but they do not fit in with the rest of your example very well. I can think of a few ways to rephrase your example:

> Medicine is very important, which can
>   be ascertained from...
>
> Medicine is very important. The fact
>   that ... proves its importance.

Why exactly do you want to do away with this "this"? It looks fine in your example. A bit more context (purpose?) might get you better suggestions. Is this a real sentence, or just an example?

Comment: I'm already using "This" in nearby sentences, that's why I wanted to vary. :) I like your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most succinct way that I can conjure to rephrase your connected pair of statements would convert the second statement into a dependent clause of the first. E.g.:

> Medicine is very important, as proved by...

Comment: ..Good answer..

Answer (score -2):

Flip the sentence around: There exist many fatal diseases in the world which are curable and why medicine is very important.

Much better.

Comment: Except the your version of the sentence makes less sense.

Comment: It's ungrammatical.

Comment: "I Am America (And So Can You!) "

Comment: @Mitch Unh-Unh L'état, c'est moi. [Do I dare say it? This is a joke]