# Preposition to follow "Further acknowledgment"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, prepositions

I have a statement. And after that statement I have:

> This is further acknowledged by the
>   consolidation of the material.

But I want to remove the "This". What preposition can I use here:

> Further acknowledgement **arrives** from
>   the consolidation of the material.

.

I'm not sure if "arrives" should is correct or formal enough. This is for a PhD thesis.

Comment: Why are you [on a mission to remove *this* everywhere](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/)? What has that poor word ever done to you? It's an excellent and most useful word. Trying to get rid of it will only make your writing clumsier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say

> We receive further acknowledgement from the consolidation of the material.

or

> Further acknowledgement comes from the consolidation of the material.

or

> The consolidation of the material constitutes further acknowledgement.

and so on.

I too wonder, as does @RegDwight, why the demonstrative pronoun *this* bothers you so much? I find this very puzzling, as *this* is not only common and clear but allows for more succinct referencing of subjects than other constructions might. The only time it becomes difficult to parse is when the antecedent is unclear (e.g., when it is the subject of a clause or sentence which might refer to multiple subjects from a previous clause or sentence).

Comment: The premise of the sentence seems wrong to me. Shouldn't acknowledgement be performed by some agent? Consolidation doesn't seem like a source of acknowledgements.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly less verbose:

> Further acknowledgement follows the consolidation of the material.

or, slightly more precise:

> Further acknowledgement results from consolidation of the material.

Side note: I hope that your context answers the questions: "Acknowledgement of what?" and "What material?".